# Combining 2D matrices of different size into a 3D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, concatenation

I have a loop and for each iteration there is 2D matrix being created and I am concatenating those matrices into a new 3D matrix. However the dimensions do not always match and it does not work. An example of the code is below:

```
for Set=1:3
    if Set == 1 || Set == 2
        M=zeros(1200,162); %size 1200x162
    else 
        M=zeros(1200,159); %size 1200x159
    end
    
    FinalM(:,:,Set) = M;  % Final matrix should be a 3Dmatrix of 1200x362x3
end
```

But I get the error
`Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is 1200-by-162 and the size of the right side is 1200-by-159.`

Is there a way to still concatenate the matrices and have a final 3D ignoring the error about the dimensions?

Comment: You'll likely have to pad the smaller matrices by zero to fit their shape to the larger ones, s.t. you get a cube with the base-size of the largest matrix.

Comment: No, a 3D matrix is a matrix of size NxMxP, its conceptually not logical to have different size of 2D matrices concatenated. You said your final matrix should be`1200x362x3`. Where do these numbers come from? How do you fill only part of the matrix? what happens with the part that is not "filled"?

Comment: If you really need matrices of different dimensions, consider using a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) of matrices